# problem with installing nvidia-173 driver ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

My graphics card is a GeForce fx5200. After installing the nvidia drivers, the resolution of my pc monitor is limited to 640x480 and 320x240-

I installed the packages nvidia-173, nvidia-173-updates and nvidia-96 on the 3 different Ubuntu versions (10.10, 12.04, 13.04).

Is there any solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to install only nvidia-173 and the directions are here:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=102602

It should be pretty much the same for ubuntu